# Is the SilverlightFaultBehavior class required for Silverlight 4?

Tags: c#, silverlight, wcf

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee844556%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) says

> Silverlight version 4 enables support for the Windows Communication
>   Foundation (WCF) SOAP fault programming model, which allows the
>   service to communicate error conditions to the client. In previous
>   versions of Silverlight, if an error occurred on the service, it would
>   register as an HTTP 500 response code and details about the error
>   would not be accessible to the Silverlight client.

However a number of other locations suggest using this still for Silverlight 4 clients and the above seems fairly ambiguous on what to do for Silverlight 4.  I was wondering if anyone could confirm what approach should be used for handling WCF errors on Silverlight 4.

Comment: Earlier developers were forced to include errors to the returned object. Now it is possible to use fault exceptions, which is much more convenient and compatible with other clients. There is nothing ambiguous there. Maybe you meant something different in your question, I haven't understood exactly.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, if you want to catch faults in a Silverlight 4 client, you will need to use a custom WCF behavior that changes that HTTP status code from 500 to 200 when a fault is raised by the service.

See:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee844556(v=vs.95).aspx

Answer (score 1):

There are two HTTP stacks in Silverlight, one provided by the browser (the default one) and a *client stack*, which is one written using the native OS stack. If you use the first one, you need to use the fault behavior to convert from 500 to 200 in the service. But if you use the client stack, you should be able to consume "normal" faults in SL.

More information about this at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2009/08/15/fault-support-in-silverlight-3.aspx.